# How do I show that two sets of spectra are different?

Tags: statistics

I essentially have 6 spectral curves, 3 repeats for two samples. I want to be able to show that two samples are distinct (if they are). I have tried spearman's correlation already, which does produce p values however I feel like I've very much hacked them and that the p value doesn't tell me if they curves are different like an anova test would say. One idea I had was doing PCA and anova on the first PC. Would this be valid?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: This is also discussed here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_way_to_compare_two_spectral_data_and_how_to_quantify